# Select Specific StarData

Tags: filtering, curated-data, astronomy

The help menu for StarData has many examples such as

```
StarData[EntityClass[
  "Star", {EntityProperty["Star", "DistanceFromEarth"] -> 
    TakeSmallest[10]}]]
```

which are great. However, I'd like to select not the smallest, but stars that fall in a specific distance range, i.e., 100 - 200 ly from Earth (or range of any other property). I tried various options, but could not get it to work with a range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
StarData[
    EntityClass[
        "Star",
        "DistanceFromEarth" -> Between[{Quantity[100,"ly"],Quantity[200,"ly"]}]
    ]
]
```

or:

```
EntityList @ EntityClass[
    "Star",
    "DistanceFromEarth" -> Between[{Quantity[100,"ly"],Quantity[200,"ly"]}]
]
```

Comment: Great – works. I tried Between, but forgot I need the Quantity. Thanks for this heads up.